# How to switch graphes (on Neo4j)?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

How do I come back on the Neo4J graph after using

```
g = new TinkerGraph()
```

I guess it's something like

```
g.loadGraphML(...)
```

EDIT:

Your answer helped me to better understand how loadGraphML() works, but it didn't solve my problem.

I'm going to rephrase my question. I use Neo4j and Gremlin, and when I first start the server, I get the following lines under Gremlin console.

```
==> Available variables:
==>   g = neo4jgraph[EmbeddedGraphDatabase [/home/user/software/neo4j-community-1.5.M01/data/graph.db]]
```

Then I type

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==> tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
```

But how can I come back to "g = neo4jgraph[EmbeddedGraphDatabase [/home/user/software/neo4j-community-1.5.M01/data/graph.db]]"

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your question, but I believe you mean that you have done some work with TinkerGraph and you want to import that data into Neo4jGraph? Moreover, given that you are doing g.loadGraphML(...), I will assume you are talking about doing this from [Gremlin](http://gremlin.tinkerpop.com). If not, please use the respective [GraphMLReader/Writer](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/GraphML-Reader-and-Writer-Library) classes provided by [Blueprints](http://blueprints.tinkerpop.com).

```
gremlin> g
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.V
==>v[3]
==>v[2]
==>v[1]
==>v[6]
==>v[5]
==>v[4]
gremlin> h = new Neo4jGraph('/tmp/test')
==>neo4jgraph[EmbeddedGraphDatabase [/tmp/test]]
gremlin> g.saveGraphML('test.xml') 
==>null
gremlin> h.loadGraphML('test.xml')
gremlin> h.V
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
==>v[4]
==>v[5]
==>v[6]
```

In short, you can output your graph to GraphML from TinkerGraph and then load it up into Neo4jGraph via the loadGraphML() method. There is a GraphMigrator tool in Blueprints that you might be interested---see the Blueprints [JavaDoc](http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blueprints/1.0/api/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Within the gremlin console, you should be able to just type:
g = new Neo4jGraph("/home/path_to_your_neo4j/data/graph.db")

Let me know if this answers your question.